# Need to call same NGRX effects from same effects if error occurred

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I need to call NGRX effects back to back two times, So first time if an effect get error then change the parameters data and again call the same effect.

For example: Below is my action which I want to call back to back two times in specific error code.

```
connect$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(MVHostActions.connect),
        withLatestFrom(
            this.store.pipe(select(selectService)),
            this.store.pipe(select(selectUser)),
        ),
        exhaustMap(([{ mvHost, route, navExtras, isUsingUserDefinedCustomViews },
        isService, appUser]) => 
            this.apiService.connect(mvHost).pipe(
                exhaustMap((apiResponse) => {
                    .....
                    .....
                }),
                takeUntil(this.actions$.pipe(ofType(MVHostActions.cancel))),
                catchError((error: any) => of(MVHostActions.connectToFailure({ error, navExtras, mvHost, route,isUsingUserDefinedCustomViews })))
            )
            )));
```

So during this effects if effects got error so in failure effects I did below things.

```
connectToFailure1$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(MVHostActions.connectToFailure),
        filter((error) => (error?.error?.error?.error?.code === DATASETS_ERROR || error?.error?.error?.error?.code === ARCHIVED_DATASETS_ERROR)),
        mergeMap(({navExtras,mvHost,route,isUsingUserDefinedCustomViews}) => {
                
               //Change the necessary data to by-pass that error
                
            return of (
                MVHostActions.connect({ navExtras, mvHost, route,isUsingUserDefinedCustomViews })
            );
        })
    ));
```

So from above failure effect, I need to call "connect" effect again based on error code.

If you can provide in different structure that is also ok OR you can provide the architecture of effects calling in this scenario that is also good for me.

Thanks to all...

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question. Are you looking for advice on how to do this in a different way?

Imho, the proposed solution is fine, and I've used it before.

```
Action A
Effect A => Error => Action B
Effect B => Action A
Effect A
```

Depending on the logic to update the params, it would also be OK for the effect to dispatch the same action.

```
Action A
Effect A => Error => Action A
Effect A
```

Comment: Hey, yes am looking for the way to resolve this issue. Is it possible to provide code for this scenario?